# Cocoa resize window hides controls

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nib

I am working on a cocoa project, utilizing auto layout. I let Xcode automatically pick the constrains for me.

When I simulate the document, it looks good, the controls adjust accordingly with the window.

When I run the project, the controls stay in a static position and the window moves around it causing the controls to become hidden, see image below.

[image: Controls Cut Off]

In my AppDelegate.m, all I have is this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    self.masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

There is a MainMenu.xib that I haven't touched. The issue I  am experiencing is with the MasterViewController.

I can't seem to figure out how to make the controls adjust with window resize...

This is my first cocoa project =)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to adjust the constraints accordingly to tell the auto layout system what you want - it's not a precog :-) Explaining the whole constraints system in a single response won't work, that's what Apple's docs are for..

Comment: But re-sizing when simulating the document works fine, the controls adjust accordingly. So I thought that would show me how it would run. However I think the issue might be in the parent window...

Comment: I have a Window with a custom View Controller in it. When I resize the window, the view controller gets hidden by the new dimensions of the Window.

Comment: It feels like we'd need to see the constraints you've defined for the constraints across the window (width, leading/trailing space and space between objects in the left-right orientation).